# Symfony : multiple "for" loops in Twig

Tags: symfony, for-loop, twig

I have all these {% for %} loops that are nested one inside the other but I would like them to be all at the same level. Independent from one another because like this, my goalkeepers only appear if there are defenders, midfielders... I would like them all to appear wether one category is missing or not.

```
 <tbody>
            {% for defenser in defensers %}
            {% for midfielder in midfielders %}
            {% for forward in forwards %}
            {% for gk in goalkeepers %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="player-in-club">
                        <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': gk.id }) }}">{{ gk.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="player-in-club">
                        <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': defenser.id }) }}">{{ defenser.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="player-in-club">
                        <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': midfielder.id }) }}">{{ midfielder.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="player-in-club">
                        <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': forward.id }) }}">{{ forward.name }}</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %} 
            {% endfor %} 
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that your arrays always contain at least one (empty string) Element if you put this in front of your for loops:

```
{% if defensers is empty %}
    {% set defensers = [""] %}
{% endif %}
{% if midfielders is empty %}
    {% set midfielders = [""] %}
{% endif %}
{% if forwards is empty %}
    {% set forwards = [""] %}
{% endif %}
{% if goalkeepers is empty %}
    {% set goalkeepers = [""] %}
{% endif %}
```

But I feel like you want something kompletely differently. The way you have set up your loops they will print every possible row kombination.

If you just want a table that is filled as the items are available you might want to use this instead of your loops:

```
    {% set row_count = max(defensers|length, midfielders|length, forwards|length, goalkeepers|length) %}
    <tbody>
        {% for index in range(0, row_count - 1) %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="player-in-club">
                    {% if goalkeepers[index] %}
                        <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': goalkeepers[index].id }) }}">{{ goalkeepers[index].name }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="player-in-club">
                    {% if defensers[index] %}
                    <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': defensers[index].id }) }}">{{ defensers[index].name }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="player-in-club">
                    {% if midfielders[index] %}
                    <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': midfielders[index].id }) }}">{{ midfielders[index].name }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="player-in-club">
                    {% if forwards[index] %}
                    <a href="{{ path('show_player', {'id': forwards[index].id }) }}">{{ forwards[index].name }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it but I get an error that says : "Key "1" for array with keys "0" does not exist."

Comment: Add `default` to every `if`, e.g. `{% if forwards[index]|default %}`

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly ! Could you just explain what the ’default’ does ?

Comment: See the documentation [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html). It is kinda like doing `if isset($forwards[$index])` to account for non-existing elements in the array